# getting the comment attribute of nodes/edges in graphviz in svg format

Tags: jquery, svg, visualization, graphviz, dot

I am trying to create an interactive graph, for which I am using the `neato -n -Tsvg` command, and then including javascript code for the graph in svg format.

However, for this interactivity, I need some extra information about the nodes and edges that I am putting in the [`comment`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/comment/) attributes while generating the DOT code. However, the comment attribute does not appear in the svg format. Is there some way I can get this information in the svg format?

I cannot use the [`id`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/id/) attribute of nodes/edges because id's need to be unique for each node/edge and in my case multipe nodes/edges share the same comment data.

Any way to accomplish what I am trying?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`class="YOUR_CLASS_NAME"`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/class/) attribute, it allows the same values for different nodes and edges.

For example, let's set the same `cat` class for nodes. Script:

```
digraph {
    graph [class="cats"];

    "Lion" [pos="0,0" class="yellow social cat"];
    "Snow Leopard" [pos="0,0" class="white solitary cat"];
}
```

Result svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by graphviz version 6.0.1 (20220911.1526)
 -->
<!-- Pages: 1 -->
<svg width="138pt" height="44pt" viewBox="0.00 0.00 137.99 44.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="graph0" class="graph cats" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 40)">
        <polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="-4,4 -4,-40 133.99,-40 133.99,4 -4,4" />
        <!-- Lion -->
        <g id="node1" class="node yellow social cat">
            <title>Lion</title>
            <ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="64.99" cy="-18" rx="27.1" ry="18" />
            <text text-anchor="middle" x="64.99" y="-14.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">Lion</text>
        </g>
        <!-- Snow Leopard -->
        <g id="node2" class="node white solitary cat">
            <title>Snow Leopard</title>
            <ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="64.99" cy="-18" rx="64.99" ry="18" />
            <text text-anchor="middle" x="64.99" y="-14.3" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">Snow Leopard</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```